# Aspell add word to personal dictionary using pipes

Tags: aspell

I'm using Aspell through pipes, and would like to know how can I add a new word to my personal dictionary.

For example, to check spelling for the word "tesst" I use:

```
echo tesst|aspell -a -p .aspell.en_US.pws
```

[Here](http://aspell.net/man-html/Through-A-Pipe.html#Through-A-Pipe) is explained that I can use "*word" to add this word to my personal dictionary:

```
echo *tesst|aspell -a -p .aspell.en_US.pws
```

But it doesn't.

What I'm doing wrong?.

Answer (score 0):

Have you saved your personal dictionary ?

`A line prefixed with # will cause the personal dictionaries to be saved.`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I could not make Aspell6 working with personal dictionaries. Instead I had to create extra-dictionaries as I explain at http://vouters.dyndns.org/tima/Linux-Windows-Perl-Aspell-Determining_the_country_of_a_Web_query.html. Otherwise I was getting an error from Aspell. If you read the Perl code at the above URL it uses the Aspell6 'extra-dicts' feature. This was my only workaround to Aspell's personal dictionaries.

FYI: the goal of the Perl code is to determine the language spoken by a Web visitor leaving his query into a company's Web search engine. All the queries are stored within an xlsx Excel file. The final purpose is to determine whether the translation of a company's English written Web document is financially worth to translate it to a local dialect.

In the hope this will help you.
Philippe Vouters (Fontainebleau/France)